# How do I get my look to skip over if user exist in adgroup?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

I've tried to many different methods but I'm still recieving the same error message as seen below. Does anyone have a solution for this?

the code:

```
$RolesCollection = @()
$Roles = Get-MsolRole
ForEach ($Role In $Roles){
  $Members = Get-MsolRoleMember -RoleObjectId $Role.ObjectId
  ForEach ($Member In $Members) {
    $data = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
      MemberObjectID = $Member.ObjectId
    }
    $RolesCollection += $data
  }
#Adds users with admin roles into PIM group via member object ID
      forEach ($user in $RolesCollection){

      #check if the user exists in the AAD Group, if not, add into it.
      $members = Get-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $adGroup | Select -ExpandProperty ObjectID


        If ($members -contains $user) {
            
            Write-Output " $user exist in $adgroup"

         } Else {
            Add-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $adGroup -RefObjectId $($user.MemberObjectID)
         }

      }
}
```

and this is the error message:

Add-AzureADGroupMember : Error occurred while executing AddGroupMember
Code: Request_BadRequest
Message: One or more added object references already exist for the following modified
properties: 'members'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$members` doesn't include the `$user` because their types are different.

You need to get the AAD user using `Get-AzureADUser`.

```
#Adds users with admin roles into PIM group via member object ID
      forEach ($user in $RolesCollection){

      $targetUser = Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId $user.MemberObjectID | Select -ExpandProperty ObjectID

      #check if the user exists in the AAD Group, if not, add into it.
      $members = Get-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $adGroup | Select -ExpandProperty ObjectID


        If ($members -contains $targetUser) {
            
            Write-Output " $targetUser exist in $adgroup"

         } Else {
            Add-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $adGroup -RefObjectId $($user.MemberObjectID)
         }

      }
```